# program using recursions to calculate nth element of Fibonacci series in c

Tags: c, recursion, compiler-errors, fibonacci

gdb compiler is showing an error to the code below. why did the error occur and how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int s(int n);
int main(){
    int n;
    printf("enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d",s(n));
    return 0;
}
int s(int n){
    s(1) = 1;                      //error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    s(2) = 1;                     //error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    s(n) = s(n-1) + s(n-2);      //error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    return s(n);
}
```

Comment: Your code is bogus. You can *READ* a result *RETURNED* by a C function.  You *CANNOT* assign a value *TO* a function!

Comment: `gdb` is a *debugger* not a compiler. `gcc` is the compiler frontend program one usually invokes to build (compile and link).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong, as @paulsm4 pointed out, you cannot assign value to a function. Change your `s` function to this:

```
int s(int n){
 if(n <= 2){
  return 1;
 }                     
 return s(n-1) + s(n-2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant to write was the equivalent of

```
fib(1) = 1;
fib(2) = 1;
fib(n) = fib(n - 1) + fib(n -2);
```

In C, you can't assign a value to the result returned by a function. So something like

```
foo(1) = 1;
```

is incorrect code. To explain the compiler error, you need to understand what an `lvalue` is. To put it simplistically, an `lvalue` is something to which you can assign a value and take its address. One way to think of it is that `lvalue` *usually* appears on the left hand side of an expression. So for something like

```
int x = 2;
```

`x` is an `lvalue` since you are assigning to it and you can take the address of `x` (using `&x`). This isn't true for the value returned by a function.

Coming to your original problem

```
int s(int n){
    s(1) = 1;
    s(2) = 1;
    s(n) = s(n-1) + s(n-2);
    return s(n);
}
```

As discussed above statements like `s(1) = 1` etc. are incorrect code. So `fib(1) = 1` should translate to a function that returns the value of 1. Similarly for 2. For any general `n` you need to write the function that uses these base cases and then return the actual value.

So something like

```
int s(int n){
    if(n == 1 || n == 2) { //Base case
       return 1;
    }
    return s(n-1) + s(n-2); //Recursion
}
```